# C++ - One-liner to iterate nested brace-enclosed lists?

Tags: c++

In Python we can do

```py
for i, j in [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]:
    ...
```

Is there something similar in C++?

In the non-nested case there is

```cpp
for (auto i : {0, 1});
```

but extending to nested lists

```cpp
for (auto [i, j] : {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}});
```

doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

void foo() {
    for (auto [i, j] : std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>> {
           {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}
        );
}
```

and note you have to include the two headers.

You can also use this shorter version:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

void bar() {
    for (auto [i, j] :  {std::pair{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}});
}
```

and again - you need to include *both* of these headers.

(See it all on [<kbd>Godbolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/hM1fWsv7x))